# Google Firebase's signInAnonymously function crashes my Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to follow a simple Flutter and Firebase tutorial that I found on YouTube. At the moment the app is just a simple login screen with a button that tries to sign the user in using the signInAnonymously function that Firebase provides.

However, every time I click the button to sign in the app crashes but, the new user is created and can be seen under authentication->users in the Firebase Console.

Here is the output from the debug console:

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 2621): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@e0bea08
W/DynamiteModule( 2621): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 2621): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth( 2621): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
E/JavaBinder( 2621): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder( 2621): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcl.zzdx(Unknown Source:13)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
E/JavaBinder( 2621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app-uIKbQPsmHSCIvS-nf2ZtLQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app-uIKbQPsmHSCIvS-nf2ZtLQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app-uIKbQPsmHSCIvS-nf2ZtLQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/JavaBinder( 2621):    ... 16 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:2621_1
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621): Process: com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app, PID: 2621
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcl.zzdx(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app-uIKbQPsmHSCIvS-nf2ZtLQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app-uIKbQPsmHSCIvS-nf2ZtLQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app-uIKbQPsmHSCIvS-nf2ZtLQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2621):    ... 16 more
I/Process ( 2621): Sending signal. PID: 2621 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I'll also include my project build.gradle below:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my android/app build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.teegeedigital.teegee_digital_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm relatively new to Mobile App Development so please let me know if I should include anything else. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate to androidx, you can do that by adding:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In the android/gradle.properties.

You can find more about migration to androidx in this flutter guide:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration